Find smallest base such that integer exceeds M in O(log M) time

You are given a string s consisting of digits 0-9 and of length at least two. Further, you are given an integer M. Find the smallest base b such that the string s when interpreted in base-b exceeds M.

For example, if s = 12 and M = 34, then b = 33 because 33 + 2 = 35 > M and 32 + 2 = 34 <= M.
We can solve this problem is O(|S| * log M) time by binary searching on the base. This is because checking if number > M takes O(|S|) time (by going through the characters of the string) and binary search takes O(log M) time.
My question is how to solve this problem in O(|S| + log M) time. I am thinking of checking the binary search in O(1) amortized - which would give the desired result. But, I can't think of how this optimization could be done. Perhaps we could store the value in a base and use it to compute other bases? Any help would be appreciated.

Hint: log(M)/log(b), the number of base-b digits in M is O(1).

@MSalters Sorry if I am too obtuse, but I don't understand your hint. Could you please elaborate further?

You know that s (base b)>M implies s has at least as many digits as M. So you have an O(1) technique to get a first approximation of b: log(b0)=floor(log(M)/ |S| )

@MSalters, your hint is interesting, but s doesn't need to have "at least as many digits" as M: 999 (base 16) is greater than 1234 but has less digits

@gimix: 999 (base 16) is obviously smaller than 1234 (base 16). (This also holds for any base in which 999 is a valid number, you can't have 999 base 2). That's why I specifically wrote "base-b digits in M". It seems you're assuming base-10 for M but not for s. The insight here is that the comparison s<M is equivalent to log(s)<log(M), and that the number of digits in a number is approximately the log of that number in the appropriate base.

Is this known that it can be done in O(|S| + log M)?

We can get a very good approximation to the actual solution when we consider that the first digit in s represents its value multiplied by b^(|s|-1); so let's compute the first approximation, call it b0, dividing M by s[0] and extracting the |s|-1th root of the result (rounded down).
If s(base b0) <= M we know that s(base b0 +1) > M is true, so we have the solution. If s(base b0) > M we will have to check b0-1, b0-2, ... until we reach the smallest base that still gives a number larger than M. I didn't find a mathematical proof of how many steps may be needed, but I ran quite a few random generated tests and at worst b0 had to be decreased by two, i.e. s(base b0 -3) <= M was true.
There are a couple of edge cases that we must deal with: leading zeroes have to be stripped, and we must avoid considering a base for which s would be illegal: for instance for M = 37 and s = 170 we would get b0 = 6 while the minimum base we can use (and the solution!) is obviously 8.
Here's a Python implementation:
def smallest_base(s, M):
    s = s.lstrip('0')
    if len(s) == 0:
        return False
    s_digits = len(s)
    s_first = int(s[0])
    b_min = int(max(s, key=int)) + 1
    b0 = max(b_min, int((M / s_first)**(1/(s_digits-1))))
    x = int(s, base=b0)
    if x < M:
        return b0+1
    if b0 == b_min:
        return b0
    while x >= M and b0 > b_min:
        b0 -= 1
        x = int(s, base=b0)
    return b0+1

Note: the Python int() function interprets a string as a value in a given base but only accepts bases up to 36, so one should write a custom function to handle larger bases.

3?? I get 19, which is the expected value

Oops, I must’ve done something wrong, sorry!

If we can claim that the linear search on the base is similar to O(log M), wouldn’t that be similar to OPs initial complexity that we’d like to improve?

The complexity of the linear search is not a direct function of M. The number of steps depends mainly on how near M is to (b0+1)^(|s|-1), and on the difference between s[0] and s[1]. That's why it is difficult to evaluate the actual complexity
